# Hide a process from Windows 8 TaskManager

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-8, process, taskmanager

I want to hide a process from Windows 8 TaskManager.

Time ago I've found a Class titled "TMListViewDelete" which is a little famous (and underground) on internet, a person did a necessary modifications in the class to work with windows Vista/7 TaskManager, and a few days ago I did all the necessary modifications to turn the Class into a couple of generic functions with some options.

...but even modified much parts of the code I don't understand the code at 100%, I know it reads the class names from Taskmanager process and then delete an item (a row), I can notice this is not the best method to hide a process from taskmanager, but this is what I have.

What I need is to implement/extend the functionality to work with windows 8 x86/x64 TaskManager, but like I've said even if I find the class names of win8 task manager I don't know how to add the functionality or where to write in the code.

This is the Class:

```
#Region " Hide Process From TaskManager "

' [ Hide Process From TaskManager ]
'
' // By Elektro H@cker
'
' Examples :
'
' Hide_Process_From_TaskManager.Processes_Names = {Process.GetCurrentProcess.ProcessName, "cmd", "notepad.exe"} ' Processes to hide.
' Hide_Process_From_TaskManager.Task_Manager_Window_Titles = {"Administrador de tareas de Windows", "Windows Task Manager"} ' Support for unknown TaskManager Window Titles.
' Hide_Process_From_TaskManager.Hide_Interval = 3 ' Hidding Interval.
' Hide_Process_From_TaskManager.Running = True ' Start hidding processes.
' Hide_Process_From_TaskManager.Running = False ' Stop hidding processes.

#Region " Hide Process From TaskManager Class "

Imports Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Text
Imports System.ComponentModel

Module Hide_Process_From_TaskManager

#Region " API's "

    Private Delegate Function EnumDelegate(ByVal lngHwnd As IntPtr, ByVal lngLParam As Integer) As Integer
    Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal Hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer
    Private Declare Function EnumChildWindows Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWndParent As IntPtr, ByVal lpEnumFunc As EnumDelegate, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer
    Private Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal lpString As System.Text.StringBuilder, ByVal cch As Integer) As Integer
    Private Declare Function GetWindowTextLength Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextLengthA" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr) As Integer
    Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Integer

    <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
    Private Sub GetClassName(ByVal hWnd As System.IntPtr, ByVal lpClassName As System.Text.StringBuilder, ByVal nMaxCount As Integer)
    End Sub

#End Region

#Region " Variables "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' The processses to hide from TaskManager.
    ''' Caution: The process name is Case-Sensitive.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Processes_Names() As String = {Process.GetCurrentProcess.ProcessName} ' The current process.

    ''' <summary>
    ''' The interval time in ms to hide the process from TaskManager.
    ''' Values greater than "5" can cause bad visual effects in TaskManager processes list.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Hide_Interval As Int32 = 3 ' ms

    ''' <summary>
    ''' The known Window Titles for Task Manager process.
    ''' This is necessary to work properly in all languages.
    ''' Add here your own Task Manager Window Tittle if is not inside.
    ''' Default support: Spanish, English, Deutsch
    ''' </summary>
    Public Task_Manager_Window_Titles() As String = { _
        "Administrador de tareas de Windows", _
        "Windows Task Manager", _
        "Windows Task-Manager", _
    }

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets the next process in the Processes_Names array to hide it.
    ''' Don't touch this.
    ''' </summary>
    Public MyProc As String

    Dim t As New Timer
    Dim hwnd As IntPtr
    Dim controls As String
    Dim ProcLV As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero

    Private Const LVM_FIRST = &H1000
    Private Const LVM_DELETECOLUMN = LVM_FIRST + 28
    Private Const LVM_GETITEMCOUNT = (LVM_FIRST + 4)
    Private Const LVM_SORTITEMS = (LVM_FIRST + 48)
    Private Const LVM_DELETEITEM = (LVM_FIRST + 8)
    Private Const LVM_GETNEXTITEM = (LVM_FIRST + 12)
    Private Const LVM_GETITEM = (LVM_FIRST + 75)

#End Region

#Region " Properties "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Turns ON/OFF the process hiding.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Property Running() As Boolean
        Get
            If t.Enabled = True Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            If value = True Then

                If Processes_Names.Length = 0 Then Throw New Exception("Processes_Names Array is empty.")
                If Hide_Interval <= 0 Then Throw New Exception("Hide_Interval value is too low, minimum value: 1")

                MyProc = Processes_Names(0)
                If Not t.Interval = Hide_Interval Then
                    With t
                        AddHandler t.Tick, AddressOf t_Tick
                        .Interval = Hide_Interval
                        .Enabled = True
                        .Start()
                    End With
                Else
                    t.Enabled = True
                    t.Start()
                End If
            Else
                t.Enabled = False
                t.Stop()
                ProcLV = IntPtr.Zero
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

#End Region

#Region " Timer Tick event "

    Private Sub t_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        If ProcLV = IntPtr.Zero Then

            For Each Title In Task_Manager_Window_Titles
                hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, Title)
                If hwnd <> 0 Then
                    EnumChildWindows(hwnd, New EnumDelegate(AddressOf Hide_Process_From_TaskManager.EnumChildWindows), 0)
                End If
            Next

        Else
            GetListView(hwnd, ProcLV)
        End If
    End Sub

#End Region

#Region " Functions "

    ' EnumChildWindows
    Private Function EnumChildWindows(ByVal lngHwnd As IntPtr, ByVal lngLParam As Integer) As Integer
        Dim strClassName As String = ObtenerClase(lngHwnd)
        Dim strText As String = ObtenerTextoVentana(lngHwnd)
        If InStr(strClassName, "SysListView32") Then
            GetListView(hwnd, lngHwnd)
            If InStr(strText, "Procesos") Then
                ProcLV = lngHwnd
            End If
        End If
        Dim Classes As String = lngHwnd.ToString & ", " & strClassName & ", " & strText
        Return 1
    End Function

    ' ObtenerClase
    Private Function ObtenerClase(ByVal handle As IntPtr) As String
        Dim strClassName As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        strClassName.Length = 255
        GetClassName(handle, strClassName, strClassName.Length)
        Return strClassName.ToString
    End Function

    ' ObtenerTextoVentana
    Private Function ObtenerTextoVentana(ByVal handle As IntPtr) As String
        Dim titleText As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        titleText.Length = GetWindowTextLength(handle) + 1
        GetWindowText(handle, titleText, titleText.Length)
        Return titleText.ToString
    End Function

#End Region

End Module

Module GetItems

#Region " API's "

    ' OpenProcess
    <DllImport(kernel32, SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Function OpenProcess(ByVal dwDesiredAccess As UInteger, ByVal bInheritHandle As Boolean, ByVal dwProcessId As Integer) As SafeProcessHandle
    End Function

    ' ReadProcessMemoryW
    <DllImport(kernel32, EntryPoint:="ReadProcessMemory", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)> _
    Private Function ReadProcessMemoryW(ByVal hProcess As SafeProcessHandle, ByVal lpBaseAddress As IntPtr, ByVal lpBuffer As StringBuilder, ByVal nSize As Integer, ByRef bytesRead As Integer) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
    End Function

    ' ReadProcessMemory
    <DllImport(kernel32, SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)> _
    Private Function ReadProcessMemory(ByVal hProcess As SafeProcessHandle, ByVal lpBaseAddress As IntPtr, ByVal lpBuffer As StringBuilder, ByVal nSize As Integer, ByRef bytesRead As Integer) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
    End Function

    ' ReadProcessMemory
    <DllImport(kernel32, SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Function ReadProcessMemory(ByVal hProcess As SafeProcessHandle, ByVal lpBaseAddress As IntPtr, ByRef lpBuffer As LV_ITEM, ByVal nSize As Integer, ByRef bytesRead As Integer) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
    End Function

    ' ReadProcessMemory
    <DllImport(kernel32, SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Function ReadProcessMemory(ByVal hProcess As SafeProcessHandle, ByVal lpBaseAddress As IntPtr, ByRef lpBuffer As HDITEM, ByVal nSize As Integer, ByRef bytesRead As Integer) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
    End Function

    ' ReadProcessMemory
    <DllImport(kernel32, SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Function ReadProcessMemory(ByVal hProcess As SafeProcessHandle, ByVal lpBaseAddress As IntPtr, ByVal lpBuffer As IntPtr, ByVal nSize As Integer, ByRef bytesRead As Integer) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
    End Function

    ' SendMessage
    <DllImport(user32, SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal message As UInteger, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer
    End Function

    ' GetHeaderSendMessage
    <DllImport(user32, SetLastError:=True, EntryPoint:="SendMessageA")> _
    Private Function GetHeaderSendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal message As UInteger, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function

    ' SendMessage
    <DllImport(user32, SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal message As UInteger, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As StringBuilder) As Integer
    End Function

    ' SendMessage
    <DllImport(user32, SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal message As UInteger, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer
    End Function

    ' VirtualAllocEx
    <DllImport(kernel32, SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Function VirtualAllocEx(ByVal hProcess As SafeProcessHandle, ByVal lpAddress As IntPtr, ByVal dwSize As Integer, ByVal flAllocationType As UInteger, ByVal flProtect As UInteger) As IntPtr
    End Function

    ' VirtualFreeEx
    <DllImport(kernel32, SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Function VirtualFreeEx(ByVal hProcess As SafeProcessHandle, ByVal lpAddress As IntPtr, ByVal dwSize As Integer, ByVal dwFreeType As UInteger) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
    End Function

    ' WriteProcessMemory
    <DllImport(kernel32, SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Function WriteProcessMemory(ByVal hProcess As SafeProcessHandle, ByVal lpBaseAddress As IntPtr, ByRef lpBuffer As LV_ITEM, ByVal nSize As Integer, ByRef lpNumberOfBytesWritten As Integer) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
    End Function

    ' WriteProcessMemory
    <DllImport(kernel32, SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Function WriteProcessMemory(ByVal hProcess As SafeProcessHandle, ByVal lpBaseAddress As IntPtr, ByRef lpBuffer As HDITEM, ByVal nSize As Integer, ByRef lpNumberOfBytesWritten As Integer) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
    End Function

#End Region

#Region " Variables "

    Dim listViewHandle As IntPtr

    Public Const LVM_FIRST As UInteger = &H1000
    Public Const LVM_DELETEITEM As UInteger = (LVM_FIRST + 8)
    Public Const kernel32 As String = "kernel32"
    Public Const user32 As String = "user32"
    Public Const LVM_GETITEMCOUNT As UInteger = &H1004
    Public Const LVM_GETITEMTEXT As UInteger = &H102D
    Public Const LVM_GETHEADER As UInteger = &H101F
    Public Const HDM_GETIEMA As UInteger = &H1203
    Public Const HDM_GETITEMW As UInteger = &H120B
    Public Const HDM_GETITEMCOUNT As UInteger = &H1200
    Public Const HDM_GETUNICODEFORMAT As UInteger = &H2006
    Public Const HDI_TEXT As UInteger = 2
    Public Const MEM_COMMIT As UInteger = &H1000
    Public Const MEM_RELEASE As UInteger = &H8000
    Public Const PAGE_READWRITE As UInteger = 4
    Public Const PROCESS_VM_READ As UInteger = &H10
    Public Const PROCESS_VM_WRITE As UInteger = &H20
    Public Const PROCESS_VM_OPERATION As UInteger = &H8
    Public Const WM_GETTEXT As UInteger = &HD
    Public Const WM_GETTEXTLENGTH As UInteger = &HE

#End Region

#Region " Structures "

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)> _
    Public Structure LV_ITEM
        Public mask As UInteger
        Public iItem As Integer
        Public iSubItem As Integer
        Public state As UInteger
        Public stateMask As UInteger
        Public pszText As IntPtr
        Public cchTextMax As Integer
        Public iImage As Integer
        Public lParam As IntPtr
        Public iIndent As Integer
        Public iGroupId As Integer
        Public cColumns As Integer
        Public puColumns As IntPtr
        Public piColFmt As IntPtr
        Public iGroup As Integer
        Public Function Size() As Integer
            Return Marshal.SizeOf(Me)
        End Function
    End Structure

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
    Public Structure HDITEM
        Public mask As UInteger
        Public cxy As Integer
        Public pszText As IntPtr
        Public hbm As IntPtr
        Public cchTextMax As Integer
        Public fmt As Integer
        Public lParam As IntPtr
        Public iImage As Integer
        Public iOrder As Integer
        Public Function Size() As Integer
            Return Marshal.SizeOf(Me)
        End Function
    End Structure

#End Region

#Region " Functions "

    Public Function GetListView(ByVal handle As IntPtr, ByVal lvhandle As IntPtr) As Boolean
        listViewHandle = lvhandle
        Dim hParent As IntPtr = handle

        Dim id As Integer = -1
        Try
            For Each p In Process.GetProcessesByName("taskmgr")
                id = p.Id
            Next
            If id = -1 Then
                Throw New ArgumentException("Can't find process", "processName")
            End If
        Catch : Return False : End Try

        Dim hprocess As SafeProcessHandle = Nothing
        Try
            hprocess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_OPERATION Or PROCESS_VM_READ Or PROCESS_VM_WRITE, False, id)

            If hprocess Is Nothing Then
                If Marshal.GetLastWin32Error = 0 Then
                    Throw New System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
                End If
            End If

            Dim itemCount As Integer = SendMessage(listViewHandle, LVM_GETITEMCOUNT, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero)

            For row As Integer = 0 To itemCount - 1

                Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(GetItem(row, 0, hprocess))

                For Each processname In Processes_Names
                    MyProc = processname
                    If lvi.Text.Contains(Hide_Process_From_TaskManager.MyProc) Then SendMessage(listViewHandle, LVM_DELETEITEM, row, IntPtr.Zero)
                Next

            Next
        Catch : Return False
        Finally
            If hprocess IsNot Nothing Then
                hprocess.Close()
                hprocess.Dispose()
            End If

        End Try
        Return True
    End Function

    Public Function GetItem(ByVal row As Integer, ByVal subitem As Integer, _
                                ByVal hProcess As SafeProcessHandle) As String

        Dim lvitem As New LV_ITEM
        lvitem.cchTextMax = 260
        lvitem.mask = 1
        lvitem.iItem = row
        lvitem.iSubItem = subitem
        Dim pString As IntPtr
        Dim s As New StringBuilder(260)

        Try

            pString = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, IntPtr.Zero, 260, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE)
            lvitem.pszText = pString
            Dim pLvItem As IntPtr
            Try
                pLvItem = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, IntPtr.Zero, lvitem.Size, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE)
                Dim boolResult As Boolean = WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, pLvItem, lvitem, lvitem.Size, 0)
                If boolResult = False Then Throw New Win32Exception

                SendMessage(listViewHandle, LVM_GETITEMTEXT, row, pLvItem)
                boolResult = ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, pString, s, 260, 0)
                If boolResult = False Then Throw New Win32Exception
                boolResult = ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, pLvItem, lvitem, Marshal.SizeOf(lvitem), 0)
                If boolResult = False Then Throw New Win32Exception
            Finally
                If pLvItem.Equals(IntPtr.Zero) = False Then
                    Dim freeResult As Boolean = VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, pLvItem, 0, MEM_RELEASE)
                    If freeResult = False Then Throw New Win32Exception
                End If
            End Try
        Finally
            If pString.Equals(IntPtr.Zero) = False Then
                Dim freeResult As Boolean = VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, pString, 0, MEM_RELEASE)
                If freeResult = False Then Throw New Win32Exception
            End If
        End Try

        Return s.ToString

    End Function

    Friend NotInheritable Class SafeProcessHandle : Inherits SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid

        Declare Auto Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hObject As IntPtr) As Boolean

        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New(True)
        End Sub

        Public Sub New(ByVal handle As IntPtr)
            MyBase.New(True)
            MyBase.SetHandle(handle)
        End Sub

        Protected Overrides Function ReleaseHandle() As Boolean
            Return CloseHandle(MyBase.handle)
        End Function

    End Class

#End Region

End Module

#End Region

#End Region
```

Comment: I sure hope you don't find an answer to this. I can't think of any legitimate use for this code.

Comment: @zmbq Perhaps the fact of educational learning to trick the operating system somehow, and the fact of learning to use various APIs functions that are not commonly seen.

Comment: Perhaps, although you could study the same tricks by adding a smiley face to some files in Windows Explorer.

Comment: Task Manager in Windows 8 was completely rewritten from scratch. Any techniques from earlier versions of Windows will be completely ineffective. You will have to start over. It's not clear what your question is. It sounds like a "Can somebody write this program for me?" which is not what SO is about.

Comment: @zmbq: the clue is in his nickname :D

Comment: Definitely @ElektroHacker is making some kind of malicious software and he shouldn't get any help from the community. "Educational learning" - how do you want to learn something difficult like tricking operating system, if you "don't understand the code at 100%"? If you don't understand vb.net, .net at all or WinApi, please ask a question about what you don't understand. Do not ask someone to write an armed Trojan for you.

Comment: @zmbq however, sometimes you would need to hide command line arguments, if you are passing by sensitive data. Sometimes, the only way to automate things in windows implies to pass sensitive data through command line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There shouldn't be because it is not the point of the task manager. The task manager should be used to allow users to examine processes. Other things such as group policies can prevent users from viewing the task manager, but certainly not hiding the process from the task manager itself.

A question similar to yours : http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/218183/Csharp-hide-a-apllication-process-from-taskmanager

Comment: Please I would like you to read my question carefully and especially the code, it is possible to hide the process in the list of TaskManager 'cause TaskManager is a compiled exe, managed code, is so simple as getting the name of the class where is stored the listview of the processes and then delete the row of that process, that's what the code of my question dows. All I need to know is the name of thhat class for the Taskmanager of Windows 8 ('cause has a different name) and how to adapt my code to work in Windows 8 with the modified class.

Comment: Also this is a VB.NET question but any C#/VB code from 2011 can help me 'cause Windos 8 has not been yet released in that year then nobody can know in 2011 how to manage TMListViewDelete for TaskManager Classes of Windows 8. But Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to employ rootkit techniques. 
Read:

- [http://www.amazon.com/Managed-Code-Rootkits-Hooking-Environments/dp/1597495743](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1597495743)
- [http://www.amazon.com/Rootkits-Subverting-Windows-Greg-Hoglund/dp/0321294319](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321294319)
- [http://www.amazon.com/books/dp/1598220616](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1598220616)